# League of Legends amateur league?

Tags: league-of-legends

Well I was wondering if there are any amateur leagues for league of legends. Tournaments and such for people who are not in the pro scene.

Answer (score 9):

Every sunday, the ESL organises GO4LOL. If you live in Europe that might be helpful. You could also join the ESL ladders (1v1, 2v2, 5v5).
Look it up: http://www.esl.eu/

Answer (score 3):

If you want to play for fun,
I can suggest looking at pages like [Battlefy](http://www.battlefy.com)
or [Razer arena](https://arena.razerzone.com/) (which was launched just recently).

There you can often find some amateur tournaments for various regions,
plus it is really easy for admins to host a tournament.

I don't know in which division you are in, but sometimes there are restricted tournaments as well (e.g. only bronze to platinum allowed), mostly it is up to diamond 1 though.

AFAIK there are some leagues, where you can play in different divisons, according to your skill-level. It is called HouseParty5v5 (and has its own Subreddit btw)

Comment: It might be worth noting that for people who are not in the pro scene, but **want** to be, there's the official Challenger Series where challenger teams compete for a spot in the LCS. http://www.lolesports.com/en_US/articles/2016-challenger-series-qualifiers

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Not official by RIOT.

You can find tons of small tournaments in local areas. Usually made by [PC bang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC_bang) or special groups.

[Here](http://competitive.na.leagueoflegends.com/competitive/circuit) the Challenger Circuit by RIOT

Answer (score 0):

If you're a university student, then there are two leagues that run tournaments for college teams.

[Collegiate Starleague: League of Legends](http://lol.cstarleague.com/)

- More organized because they are using the CSL: Starcraft framework
- Larger prize pool
- Only one team per school

[IvyLoL](http://www.ivylol.com/)

- More casual tournament
- Can have more than one team per school

Answer (score 0):

If your from the UK there is a open tourny called UKlol,

They used to run each sunday,

here is a few of there [Videos.](http://www.twitch.tv/uklol/videos)